# GWT/Apache POI Download Servlet: Incorrect filename on download

Tags: java, excel, tomcat, gwt, servlets

I have a servlet that creates a dynamic Excel spreadsheet using `Apache POI`.  I can create the spreadsheet just fine.  However, when I use Google `Chrome` and a `Tomcat` server, the downloaded file does not reflect the correct filename.  Instead, it replaces the filename with the name of the servlet.  So, for example, I want to download a file "dr_3.xlsx", it would instead download a file called "excelService" (the name of the servlet).  All the contents are correct, just the file name is wrong.

This bug only occurs when using Google Chrome on a Tomcat Server.  It performs as expected when using `Firefox + Tomcat`, `Chrome + Jetty`, `Firefox + Jetty`, and `IE(eww) + Tomcat`.

This is the code for the doGet() method:

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("id"));
        int BUFFER = 1024 * 100;
        resp.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
        resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition:", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", "dr_" + id + ".xlsx"));
        OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = buildFile(id);
        resp.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        resp.setBufferSize( BUFFER );
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.close();
    }
```

Just to reiterate: The Excel file is fine.  The name of the file is incorrect.

Thanks ahead of time for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Fedy2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555220/fedy2), removing the colon from `"Content-Disposition"` worked.

Comment: Please feel free to [accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes:

```
resp.setHeader( "Content-Disposition:", String.format("attachment; filename=%s", "dr_" + id + ".xlsx"));
```

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/216777/1535738) SO discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but removing the quotations did not work.  It was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: Try also removing the colon from the header parameter name: "Content-Disposition".

Comment: ^ Genius.  It Worked. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.